# Mathematica: Unwanted vertical line in histogram

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, line, histogram

When changing the plot range of a histogram from Automatic to a plot range which exceeds the automatically calculated plot range, Mathematica draws an unwanted horizontal line which I cannot get rid of (see right histogram at value -4). Does anyone have a suggestion on that issue?

I'm running Mathematica V.8.0.1.0 on Mac OS 10.7.2.

```
In[1099]:=

data = {-1.2056, -1.46192, -1.30053, -2.52879, -0.99636, -1.73904, -1.164,
-1.83398,-0.97505, -0.503256, -0.63802, -0.785963, -0.711821, -0.820439, -1.8699,
-3.9659, -1.4456, -1.67021, -1.42009, -2.5644, -1.45002, -1.27806, -1.66529,
-1.67073, -3.31102, -3.38638};

HistogramLeft=Histogram[data, PlotRange -> Automatic]

HistogramRight=Histogram[data, PlotRange -> {-8, 0}]
```

[image: automatic plot range]
[image: individual plot range]

Comment: It is always better to show the full code that gives you troubles. Brett Champion noted correctly that the figures you're showing are not the product of the code you pasted in your question.

Comment: Sorry Viktor Korbel. I totally forgot that I set individual options for my histograms. That's why some information was missing in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using `Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}` (or something similar.)  If that's the case, you can turn off the normal axes entirely with `Axes->False`.

Comment: Thanks Brett Champion! You were wright: I used Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}. With Axes->False it worked! Many thanks again!

Comment: According to the docs, setting `Frame` to anything but `False` is supposed to turn off plotting the axes, by default. Yet, it has never worked that way. Will it, eventually?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the option AxesOrigin.

```
HistogramRight =  Histogram[data, PlotRange -> {-8, 0}, BarOrigin -> Left,  AxesOrigin -> {-8, 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, this is pretty easy, I think.

Try

```
HistogramRight = 
 Histogram[data, PlotRange -> {-8, 0}, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 PlotLabel -> Left, Axes -> {False, True}]
```

By the way, there is a new stack exchange for Mathematica at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/